# How do I return objects who have a list of the same type?

Tags: json, wcf, rest

I have a WCF service I am using to return REST queries with JSON data. I now have an object that has a list of the same object as a DataMember. Think of it as the Person object having a Children list. Works great in .NET, causes infinite recursion in WCF.

What's the best way to handle this?

**Update:**

I have a sample with the problem at http://www.windward.net/temp/AutoTagWeb.zip

Comment: `Works great in .NET, causes infinite recursion in WCF` Did you mean `Works great in ASP.NET`?

Comment: @crush I meant it works great writing C# code. You can give a Person object a member of their Children that is a List<Person>. There's no recursion as no one is their own ancestor (assuming no time travel). But WCF builds up the data in such a way that it does recurse infinitely.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean by WCF is doing this in such a way that it recurses infinitely (I understand the terminology, just not what you are trying to say). Can you provide some code samples and input/expected output?

Comment: @crush - please read http://blog.andrewrivers.co.uk/2009/05/problems-with-recursion-in-wcf.html - it explains the issue in detail.

Comment: This looks like an implementation issue - not a flaw in WCF. Of course cyclical references would create an infinite loop when being serialized...

Comment: @crush - the object type is circular. The objects themselves are not. I have a sample with one person who has a single child. That child has no children. The objects are not circular. Our discussion is going in circles (much like this WCF problem) so we should probably end this conversation.

Comment: Does your `MetaDataNodeBase` class contain a property for the parent object?  Can you provide the code for that class as well?

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice - base class added. And no, it does not have any properties that are classes, just primitives.

Comment: @David Thielen Thanks. Hmm, are you also using a more specific class that derives from `MetaDataNode`, and does that class have any reference-type properties? If I understand the problem described in the link you provided, that problem is because the `Employee` class had both a `LineManager` property as well as a `DirectReports` property. In your case, I see the `children` property, so I am wondering if there is some kind of `parent` property somewhere that is allowing the DataContract serializer to get into this recursive loop.

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice nope it really is this simple. The problem is WCF cannot handle recursive type declarations. Not recursive objects, but recursive type declarations in the objects. It's a known issue specific to WCF.

Comment: @DavidThielen Ok. I'm not able to reproduce the problem with the given data contracts. I *am* able to reproduce it if I add a property `[DataMember] public MetaDataNode parent { get; set; }` to the `MetaDataNode` class and ensure that it is set using the following line of code: `root.children.ForEach(item => item.parent = root);` I'm not 100% sure that your problem matches the one described in the link you referenced.